# Getting Truncation error in SQL SERVER while executing Stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am getting the below error while executing a stored procedure

```
 USE [Smart2uat]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SPJOB_ALLLOC]    Script Date: 2/11/2016 12:37:40 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO




ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPJOB_ALLLOC] AS 
declare @cardno as varchar(8)
declare @iodate as datetime
declare @iotime as varchar(8)
declare @holdername as varchar(100)

declare @IO_MSKID as varchar(7)
declare @IO_LOCATION_CODE as varchar(3)
declare @IO_COMPANY_CODE as varchar(3)
declare @IO_ACTIVITY_CODE as varchar(6)
declare @IO_FIRST_NAME as varchar(20)
declare @IO_THIRD_NAME as varchar(20)
declare @IO_EMPLOYEE_CODE as varchar(3)

declare @rows as integer
declare curatt1 cursor for
    select iodate,cardno,iotime,holdername from iodatatmp where isnull(cardno,'')<>'' and isnull(cardno,'') not like 'XXXX%' order by iotime
    open curatt1
    fetch next from curatt1 into @iodate,@cardno,@iotime,@holdername
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        if not exists(select CardNo  from iodata where iodate= @iodate and cardno= @cardno)
        begin
            select @IO_MSKID = ''
            select @IO_MSKID=MSKID,@IO_LOCATION_CODE=LOCATION_CODE,@IO_COMPANY_CODE=COMPANY_CODE,@IO_ACTIVITY_CODE=ACTIVITY_CODE,@IO_FIRST_NAME=FIRST_NAME,@IO_THIRD_NAME=THIRD_NAME,@IO_EMPLOYEE_CODE=EMPLOYEE_CODE from Employee_Mast where card_number = @cardno
            IF @IO_MSKID <> ''
                insert into iodata(cardno,iodate,iotime,holdername,IO_MSKID,IO_LOCATION_CODE,IO_COMPANY_CODE,IO_ACTIVITY_CODE,IO_FIRST_NAME,IO_THIRD_NAME,IO_EMPLOYEE_CODE) 
                values(@cardno,@iodate,@iotime,@holdername,@IO_MSKID,@IO_LOCATION_CODE,@IO_COMPANY_CODE,@IO_ACTIVITY_CODE,@IO_FIRST_NAME,@IO_THIRD_NAME,@IO_EMPLOYEE_CODE) 
        end 
    fetch next from curatt1 into @iodate,@cardno,@iotime,@holdername
    END
close curatt1
deallocate curatt1

delete from iodata  where cardno like 'XXXX%'
```

error is

```
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Procedure SPJOB_ALLLOC, Line 31
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

(0 row(s) affected)
```

Can you please help me..? I am attaching the table design of `iodatatmp` on which the cursor is fetching and the destination table - `Iodata`

[image: Iodata Design]
  [image: IOdataTmp design]

I have checked the length of the variable...and seems everything fine....Kindly help me..Thanks in advance

Comment: Definitely size not matching with data. Try to give size bit more to check and confirm the issue.

Comment: @ShakeerMirza  Error at line 31 pointing to this line`WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0` I've checked `@iodate,@cardno,@iotime,@holdername` matching with source and destination tables. Still getting error

Comment: however the line number will be base starting point of the loop. That does not mean error at loop starting. Give a try by just increasing the size of varchar fields @METALHEAD

Comment: @ShakeerMirza Thank u very much.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is caused by the fact that the size of some of the varchar type columns in `IODataTmp` are larger than the equivalent column in `IOData`.

For instance `IODataTmp.Holdername` is declared as `varchar(32)` and yet `IOData.Holdername` is declared as `varchar(20)` and so if you have a value in `IODataTmp.Holdername` that is longer than 20 characters it will fail when it tries to insert into `IOData.Holdername`. Another issue you have is that variables you have declared in the stored procedure to hold the values are a different size again, `@holdername` is declared as `varchar(100)`.

The solution is to ensure that all the column and variable sizes for a piece of data are the same.

Comment: But there I am storing the holder name in an intermediate variable `declare @holdername as varchar(100)` and storing in the destination table. IS that creating problem..?

Comment: Having the variable size bigger than the column size won't cause an error but introduces the chances of confusion and misunderstandings for no benefit.